# Integration issues with Spring Batch and Spring Integration - "No poller has been defined for endpoint" exception

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-batch, spring-integration

I went through the [Spring Integration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html) and the [examples here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp) and got a working sample for Spring Integration SFTP program. I already have a working Spring Batch program that reads a bunch of file and dumps into the Database.

I am now trying to integrate both Spring Batch and Spring Integration programs by going through the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html) and I created the below configuration.

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="inboundFileChannel"><int:queue/></int:channel>
    <int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel"/>
    <int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
            channel="inboundFileChannel"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            local-directory="file:/chofac/data/mex/registry/outbox"
            remote-directory="/chofac/SFTP/MEX/outbox"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            filename-pattern="*.txt">
        <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-rate="1000" />
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:transformer input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
        output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">
        <bean class="com.chofac.mint.integration.FileMessageToJobRequest">
            <property name="job" ref="responseFileReaderJob"/>
            <!-- <property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.name"/> -->
        </bean>
    </int:transformer>

    <batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
        reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" job-launcher="jobLauncher">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
    </batch-int:job-launching-gateway>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

    <batch:job id="responseFileReaderJob">
        <batch:step id="dailyReaderJob">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="dailyRRReader" writer="dailyRRDBWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10"/>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

I am running this program using the test case below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml","classpath:META-INF/spring/inbound-ResponseReaderJobIntegration.xml"})
public class AAASftpInboundMsgJobTriggerTest {

    @Resource(name="inboundFileChannel")
    PollableChannel localFileChannel;

    @Test
    public void runDemo(){
        System.out.println("Received first file message: " + localFileChannel.receive());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> 2014-07-01 10:51:48,987 [main] INFO 
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing 2014-07-01
>   10:51:48,988 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter -
>   Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'
>   2014-07-01 10:51:48,988 [main] ERROR
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception
>   while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2faadcc6]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [com.chofac.mint.integration.AAASftpInboundMsgJobTriggerTest@5d3ad33d]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:326)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for
>   endpoint
>   'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0',
>   and no default poller is available within the context.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller
>   has been defined for endpoint
>   'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0',
>   and no default poller is available within the context.    at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)  at
>   org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.initializeEndpoint(ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.java:238)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     ... 40 more 2014-07-01 10:51:48,992 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener
>   - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@ac44b88 testClass = SftpInboundMsgJobTriggerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod =
>   [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
>   [MergedContextConfiguration@4102799c testClass =
>   SftpInboundMsgJobTriggerTest, locations =
>   '{classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml,
>   classpath:META-INF/spring/inbound-ResponseReaderJobIntegration.xml.xml}',
>   classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles =
>   '{}', contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].

I experimented with most of the [top answers on this issue](http://goo.gl/rYfymI) from Google and the suggestions from StachOverflow as I typed this question, all of them resulted in different other errors and I seem to be getting diverted from the main issue.

Most common suggestion was to add a global poller, but this resulted in the error below:

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A poller should not be
>   specified for endpoint
>   'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1',
>   since 'outboundJobRequestChannel' is a SubscribableChannel (not
>   pollable).

(I am a newbie in all of these, Spring, Spring Batch and Spring Integration) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

I removed the poller in the #2 like the below

```
<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
    reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" job-launcher="jobLauncher">
</batch-int:job-launching-gateway>
```

and removed the global poller

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>
```

**I get the below exception:**

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for endpoint 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.chofac.mint.integration.DownloadFileRunBatch.main(DownloadFileRunBatch.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for endpoint 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.initializeEndpoint(ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.java:238)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 12 more

***However...*** if I leave the global poller the SFTP transfer happens and the job gets triggered

```
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>
```

**Update 2**

I get the below exception if I remove

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'inboundFileChannel' must be of type [org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel], but was actually of type [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:376)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:979)  at com.chofac.mint.batchintegration.SftpInboundMsgJobTriggerMain.main(SftpInboundMsgJobTriggerMain.java:16)
```

Here's my configuration again:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
        channel="inboundFileChannel"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="file:${inbound.local.directory}"
        remote-directory="${inbound.remote.directory}"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false"
        filename-pattern="*.*">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-rate="45000" />
    <!-- <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" cron="${MEX.CRON.PATTERN}"/> -->
    <!-- 0 15 10 ? * MON-FRI -->
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="inboundFileChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

<!-- <int:poller default="true" cron="${MEX.CRON.PATTERN}"/> -->

<int:transformer input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
    output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">
    <bean class="com.chofac.mint.integration.FileMessageToJobRequest">
        <property name="job" ref="responseFileReaderJob"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>

<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
    reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel" job-launcher="jobLauncher">
</batch-int:job-launching-gateway>

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
```

I am triggering this from a Main program as below:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml","classpath:META-INF/spring/batchintegration/inboundSFTPJob.xml");
PollableChannel pollableFileChannel = context.getBean("inboundFileChannel", PollableChannel.class);
System.out.println("Received first file message: " + pollableFileChannel.receive());
```

**Update 3**

Sample [Configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpInboundReceiveSample-context.xml), [JUnit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/SftpInboundReceiveSample.java), and [Spring example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html) on the web.

**Update 4**

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
        channel="inboundFileChannel"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="file:${inbound.local.directory}"
        remote-directory="${inbound.remote.directory}"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false" 
        filename-pattern ="*.*"
        local-filter="acceptAllFileListFilter">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-rate="45000" />

<bean id="acceptAllFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter"/>
```

program runs into a continuous loop with exceptions. I feel the polling happens very frequently (every second) though I have specified 45 seconds for the poller [Full configuration and logs here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Nyo0nc6S46iNNCiLH5vgIj6H4wncYVtz0uU_MZX6qDs/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Now I am running the program from a main method i.e., the program keeps polling the remote SFTP directory and copies new files to local. Other thing I notice is, even if I clear the local directory and though the program gets the files again from the remote the job does not get triggered until I restart the program. Is this a feature or an issue with my implementation? I would ideally want the program to keep polling for new files, pull in and run the batch job. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited the answer with details about file filters.

Answer (score 4):

`outboundJobRequestChannel` is a `SubscribableChannel` so you cannot have a `<poller/>` on batch-int:job-launching-gateway. `inboundFileChannel` is a `QueueChannel` so its consumer needs a poller (the transformer).

Notice `#0`, `#1` in the bean names. The `int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter` (`#0`) correctly has a poller; just remove the other one.

You don't really need a global (default) poller for this case (but it is being used for your transformer).

EDIT:

(reply to the comment on your question).

That is the default behavior. By default, the `local-filter` is an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. If you remove the file before the next poll, you can change this to an `AcceptAllFileListFilter`.

If you want to leave the file on disk, but detect it has been changed, use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`; since you are not deleting the remote file, you should also set the `filter` to an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` (actually a `CompositeFileListFilter` that wraps this filter and one of the pattern filters).

Otherwise, you'll keep fetching the same file and, without `preseve-timestamp`, the local filter will think it's a new file each time.

The persistent filters use a metadata store and use the file name and `lastModified` timestamp to determine if the filter should accept (pass) the file.

EDIT2:

That sample just dumps the file into a queue channel and received in the `main`; you have a transformer subscribed.

It's this code...

```
PollableChannel pollableFileChannel = context.getBean("inboundFileChannel", PollableChannel.class);
System.out.println("Received first file message: " + pollableFileChannel.receive());
```

That's causing you the current grief - just remove those lines from your main.

Comment: Hey Gary, I get the "No poller has been defined for endpoint 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context." error when I remove the global poller. Could you please comment? My configuration is pretty much the same as the example listed here http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html

Comment: Here's the complete configuration: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11EPiOiAZmjI8iw6qpdluegMz0WY8dg4n3nVkqrJvRTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `inboundFileChannel` is a queue channel so its subscriber needs a poller (either explicit or a default top-level poller). Or you can just remove the `<int:queue/>` element - unless you want to run multiple batch jobs in parallel.

Comment: There's an exception, could you please see Update 2

Comment: Why are you trying to receive from `inboundFileChannel`? It's no longer a `PollableChannel` and, in any case, it has a subscriber (the transformer). If you change it back to a queue channel, and put a poller on the transformer it will work, but your `main` will likely steal the message and it won't go to the transformer or launch the job.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be confused as the samples I used to make this code (posted as update 3) is inline with what is there so far. I seem to use the same method as in the samples. Could you please comment?

Comment: Edited; just remove the code from your `main` that you don't need.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help; this resolves the exception. But still the Batch Job only runs the first time. When I delete the files in my local directory, the files are fetched from the remote and placed in my local, but the job does not get triggered. Primarily I want the Spring Batch Job to get triggered everytime a new file is placed into it. Thanks in advance Gary.

Comment: That is the default behavior - files with the same name are only processed once. Change the local-filter to an `AcceptAllFileListFilter`. You can read up on filters [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound).

Comment: thanks for the help. I now changed the filter as in the update 4, the code runs in an unending loop throwing file not found exception. My guess - (1) Batch program gets triggered even before the SFTP download (2) The polling of 45 seconds is not taken into account. `Trivia: The program will only run once every day, say 5 pm. I will be deleting the files downloaded programatically.` Kindly let me know your comments. Thanks.

Comment: I already responded to you in the chat (where did it go?). You need to remove the file before the next poll and you need a unique job parameter if you wish to process the same file again: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={null=/chofac/data/MEX/registry/outbox/.DS_Store}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.][Headers={id=4a15641c-4dda-27e9-4488-9815a25eaee0, timestamp=1405459681652}]

Comment: Thanks Gary. Apologies for reposting and question again. There are many moving parts and seems to be an issue. I fixed the issue above with the below code  jobParametersBuilder.addLong("currentTime", new Long(System.currentTimeMillis())); but this creates a race condition. The files are downloaded, the job run, and the files get deleted, but even before the next poll the files get downloaded again. Not sure why. I also get an exception that the input file is missing, and the next poll nothing happens.

Comment: If you could, can we move this discussion to chat please?

Comment: I can post a new query if you think its appropriate.