# File Polling and Filtering Issues with SFTP Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am trying to pull remote files through SFTP Spring Integration and dump into my local drive, and kick-off a Spring Batch Job (Step-1 to read, process & write), followed by Step-2 where a Tasklet archives the local file downloaded to another location locally and deletes the downloaded file.

Assuming the files being downloaded is "data.service", "data.maintenance" and "data.transaction". I am only processing "data.service" but all 3 are archived and deleted.

I want the above steps to happen at a specific interval assuming that a new set of files will be overwritten at the remote location.

**Bean def**

```
<bean id="acceptAllFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter"/>
<bean id="acceptOnceFileListFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>
```

**conf**

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
        channel="inboundFileChannel"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="file:${inbound.local.directory}"
        remote-directory="${inbound.remote.directory}"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false"
        preserve-timestamp="true"
        filename-pattern="*.*"
        local-filter="acceptAllFileListFilter" >
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-rate="60000" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

*What is happening now is...*
The above triggers this sequence and runs in an unending loop, without fetching the new files from remote. Details as below:

I start with an empty local folder, and remote server has all 3 files
[Start the program]

1. Spring Integration program downloads all 3 files to local location
2. Spring Batch Job Step-1 gets triggered Tasklet (Step-2) archives the
3. local files Tasklet (Step-2) deletes the local files Spring
4. Integration program downloads all 3 files to local location (why???)
5. program keeps running Step-1 to Step-5 in an unending loop
6. New file dropped on the remote server, same (1) to (5) no job triggered

Tried replacing as below, but the program just runs once, i.e., from (1) to (5) and nothing happens

```
        local-filter="acceptOnceFileListFilter" >
```

**Expected**

1. Spring Integration program downloads all 3 files to local location
2. Spring Batch Job Step-1 gets triggered
3. Tasklet (Step-2) archives the local files
4. Tasklet (Step-2) deletes the local files
5. Spring Integration program waits for new files to be dropped in the remote location (polls every 60000 ms)
6. New file dropped on the remote server
7. Start with (1) through (6)

Per suggestion on a different [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516832/integration-issues-with-spring-batch-and-spring-integration-no-poller-has-bee/24518122?noredirect=1#comment38463336_24518122) I have a unique job parameter as below:

```
@Transformer
public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName, message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath());
    jobParametersBuilder.addLong("currentTime", new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
}
```

Tried with different combinations of filter, none served my purpose. Any sample would be of great help, struggling with this since last week.

**Here's my change per the suggestions:**

Adding a composite filter as below, but what would be the argument that will be passed to SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter? I could not see any samples in the internet.

```
<bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
            </bean>                     
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Including in the adapter as below:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
        channel="inboundFileChannel"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="file:${inbound.local.directory}"
        remote-directory="${inbound.remote.directory}"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false"  
        filter="compositeFilter">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-rate="600000" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

**Update - Changes after adding persistent filter:**

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
        channel="inboundFileChannel"
        session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="file:${inbound.local.directory}"
        remote-directory="file:${inbound.remote.directory}"
        auto-create-local-directory="false"
        delete-remote-files="false"  
        filter="compositeFilter"
        >
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="-1" fixed-rate="60000" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/>
                <constructor-arg value="*.*"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/>
                <constructor-arg value="*.*"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="redisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="port" value="7379"/>
</bean>

<bean name="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore">
    <constructor-arg name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

This gives me the exception as below. I tried the [suggestions](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/129969-ftp-inbound-adapter-stops-after-connection-reset) in the Spring forum, but I don't have a connection issues.

> 2014-07-17 22:27:14,139 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch -
>   Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive). 2014-07-17
>   22:27:14,192 [task-scheduler-1] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch - Disconnecting
>   from localhost port 22 2014-07-17 22:27:14,195 [task-scheduler-1]
>   DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
>   Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel' 2014-07-17
>   22:27:14,197 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel -
>   preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload
>   MessagingException
>   content=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem
>   occurred while synchronizing remote to local
>   directory][Headers={id=84cccecf-20ec-f67b-3f74-a938bf9abf3d,
>   timestamp=1405661234197}] 2014-07-17 22:27:14,197 [task-scheduler-1]
>   DEBUG org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - (inner
>   bean)#22 received message: [Payload MessagingException
>   content=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem
>   occurred while synchronizing remote to local
>   directory][Headers={id=84cccecf-20ec-f67b-3f74-a938bf9abf3d,
>   timestamp=1405661234197}] 2014-07-17 22:27:14,199 [task-scheduler-1]
>   ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler -
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred
>   while synchronizing remote to local directory     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:52)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:278)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on
>   session   at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$LsEntry cannot be cast to java.io.File    at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.fileName(FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:28)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.buildKey(AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.accept(AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractFileListFilter.filterFiles(AbstractFileListFilter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter.filterFiles(CompositeFileListFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.filterFiles(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:302)
>     ... 22 more
>
> 2014-07-17 22:27:14,199 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel -
>   postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload
>   MessagingException
>   content=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem
>   occurred while synchronizing remote to local
>   directory][Headers={id=84cccecf-20ec-f67b-3f74-a938bf9abf3d,
>   timestamp=1405661234197}]

**Update post removing `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` filter leaving the 'SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter'**

> 2014-07-18 09:29:21,942 [task-scheduler-3] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch -
>   Authentications that can continue:
>   publickey,keyboard-interactive,password 2014-07-18 09:29:21,942
>   [task-scheduler-3] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch - Next authentication method:
>   publickey 2014-07-18 09:29:21,942 [task-scheduler-3] INFO 
>   com.jcraft.jsch - Authentications that can continue:
>   keyboard-interactive,password 2014-07-18 09:29:21,942
>   [task-scheduler-3] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch - Next authentication method:
>   keyboard-interactive 2014-07-18 09:29:22,022 [task-scheduler-3] INFO 
>   com.jcraft.jsch - Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
>   2014-07-18 09:29:22,067 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils - Opening
>   RedisConnection 2014-07-18 09:29:22,068 [task-scheduler-3] INFO 
>   com.jcraft.jsch - Disconnecting from localhost port 22 2014-07-18
>   09:29:22,068 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel -
>   preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload
>   MessagingException
>   content=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem
>   occurred while synchronizing remote to local
>   directory][Headers={id=55304e38-6f82-8350-e763-0f5bcb507788,
>   timestamp=1405700962068}] 2014-07-18 09:29:22,068 [Connect thread
>   localhost session] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch - Caught an exception,
>   leaving main loop due to Socket closed 2014-07-18 09:29:22,068
>   [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - (inner
>   bean)#22 received message: [Payload MessagingException
>   content=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem
>   occurred while synchronizing remote to local
>   directory][Headers={id=55304e38-6f82-8350-e763-0f5bcb507788,
>   timestamp=1405700962068}] 2014-07-18 09:29:22,069 [task-scheduler-3]
>   ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler -
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred
>   while synchronizing remote to local directory     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:52)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:278)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on
>   session   at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
>     ... 21 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot
>   get Jedis connection; nested exception is
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool  at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:41)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:128)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:78)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putIfAbsent(DefaultHashOperations.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putIfAbsent(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.RedisProperties.putIfAbsent(RedisProperties.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore.putIfAbsent(RedisMetadataStore.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.accept(AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractFileListFilter.filterFiles(AbstractFileListFilter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter.filterFiles(CompositeFileListFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.filterFiles(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer$1.doInSession(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:302)
>     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool  at
>   redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:84)  at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:10)  at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:90)
>     ... 41 more Caused by:
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:150)   at
>   redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:71)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1783)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:65)     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:429)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360)
>     at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)    ... 44 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)  at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:144)   ... 51
>   more
>
> 2014-07-18 09:29:22,069 [task-scheduler-3] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel -
>   postSend (sent=true) on channel 'errorChannel', message: [Payload
>   MessagingException
>   content=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem
>   occurred while synchronizing remote to local
>   directory][Headers={id=55304e38-6f82-8350-e763-0f5bcb507788,
>   timestamp=1405700962068}]

Answer (score 3):

[Gist Here](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/854516993283495e0b40)

Hopefully self-explanatory; it just prints the file name on the console, then deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the case that if the new files dropped on the server has same name(which are downloaded in the first iteration) then spring integration will not attempt to download the files again. "acceptOnceFileListFilter" seems like something that would restrict sftp integration component to download the same file again.

**Update**: Here is some sample code which polls a remote directory every 10 secs without introducing any filters(I am not sure why you need them, as you want to download the files regardless). Given that you dont want to change the file names, the only thing that you will have to make sure is that your downloaded local needs to deleted when the next file is dropped on the remote server. I verified it and worked fine for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd">


<int:channel id="incomingChannel"/>

<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="host"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<!-- poll every 10 secs without worrying about file names-->

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="triggerFtpInBound"
                                 channel="incomingChannel"
                                 auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                 local-directory="C:\home\temp\ftp"
                                 remote-directory="/export/home/rbaljinder/ftp-test"
                                 filename-pattern="*.*"
                                 session-factory="ftpClientFactory">
    <int:poller cron="1/10 * * * * *" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

UPDATE: seems working now.Added local-filter="acceptAllFileListFilter".

```
 <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="triggerFtpInBound"
                                 channel="incomingChannel"
                                 auto-create-local-directory="true"
                                 local-directory="C:\home\temp\ftp"
                                 remote-directory="/export/home/cwk2/ftp-test"
                                 filename-pattern="*.*"
                                 session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                 local-filter="acceptAllFileListFilter">
    <int:poller cron="1/10 * * * * *" max-messages-per-poll="1"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
<bean id="acceptAllFileListFilter"
      class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter"/>
<int:service-activator id="jobServiceActivator"
                       input-channel="incomingChannel"
                       ref="triggerJobLauncher"
                       method="launch"/>

@Component("triggerJobLauncher")
public static class TriggerJobLauncher {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public void launch(File file) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test:" + file);
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree, so what would be the right combination for this scenario?

Comment: If you control the file naming convention on the sftp server, then you can use a convention which has a timestamp in the file name or something else that make the name unique.

Comment: See the [SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound) - it uses the filename and creation date. There's a file system version of the same filter that can be used as the local filter.

Comment: I am a newbie, hence pardon my petty queries. I am unsure what might be the args passed to SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter. Please help, I have the configs updated on the post. Thanks.

Comment: @rbaljinder your solution works only if the matter is pulling the file from the remote to local. This is same as my code earlier. The issue here is the jobs don't get triggered.

Comment: @GaryRussell The [spring docs refer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store) and state to use "PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore", but this Class is missing in the [latest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/store/) but available in [older versions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/integration/store/). I am not sure what's wrong here. Please correct me.

Comment: updated with new configuration but still gets some exception. Please provide me some clue to proceed. thanks.

Comment: Read the stack trace: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$LsEntry cannot be cast to java.io.File ... `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`... You are using a File system filter where you need an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`; the file system filter would be used for the `local-filter` if needed.

Comment: @oneworld Yeah just tried it out and although the file are getting downloaded subsequently, the trigger doesn't happen. This could have been because either the message wasn't put on the channel as the file name was same. I tried org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptAllFileListFilter as local filter and the problem was resolved. I have added some more code to demonstrate.

Comment: @rbaljinder Appreciate your help here, but we are going back to square one, pleas see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516832/integration-issues-with-spring-batch-and-spring-integration-no-poller-has-bee/24518122?noredirect=1#comment38463336_24518122) post.

Comment: @GaryRussel: I did realize this and tried removing the `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` filter leaving the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. It looks that the Redis is having some issue starting. Is there some good example here? I see lot of dependencies one after another to get a very simple and straight-forward scenario to be running. Probably I hope these internal dependency satisfied rather than to keep wiring things constantly.